# Duplicate go slices key values

Tags: arrays, for-loop, go

```
type Developer struct {
  Name        string   `json:"name"`
  Skills      []interface{} `json:"skills"`
}
```

This is my struct

```
var developers []Developer
var devData Developer
if searchResult.TotalHits() > 0 {
    for _, hit := range searchResult.Hits.Hits {
        err := json.Unmarshal(hit.Source, &devData)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error")
        }
        fmt.Println(devData.Skills) // utp here data are correct

        developers = append(developers, devData)
    }
    //after loop data skills value are not correct
}
```

but when actual data is made the skills are same throught all arrays

```
expected : ['name' : 'John Doe','skills': ["php","go"]], ['name' : 'Rovvie Doe','skills': ["java","haskel]]

But output :  ['name' : 'John Doe','skills': ["java","haskel"]], ['name' : 'Rovvie Doe','skills': ["java","haskel]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reusing the same `devData` variable, and therefore its allocated memory, in each iteration of the `for` loop. This means that when you call `json.Unmarshal` and pass it the pointer to `devData` you're overwriting what has been written to that memory during the previous iteration.

Instead of declaring the `devData` variable above the `if` statment, you should declare it inside the `for` loop to get a new segment of memory allocated for each of your iteration variables.

---

Note that if the type of the variable is pointer-less then you could use your original approach since Go is pass-by-value and each time you pass a variable to a function, including `append`, a *shallow* copy of that variable's value gets created.

However, since slices in go do hold a pointer to the first element of the slice the `Developer` type, because of its `Skills` field, does not qualify.

And that is why you're seeing the `Name` field getting copied correctly, but the contents of the `Skills` field getting overwritten.